# PHP/GD - transparent background

Tags: php, gd, transparency

I want to do the following in PHP in combination with GD. ImageMagick is not an option, unfortunately, but this seems like such a common problem that there *has* to be a solution, I just can't seem to find it.

I want to create a PNG with a transparent background. Then I want to draw a rectangle on it, copy an image on it, and add some text. One way of doing this is as follows:

```
$image = ImageCreateTrueColor (800, 600);
imagecolortransparent ($image, 0); //0 is pure black, the default fill color
imagerectangle (...);
//code to copy an image
imagettftext ($image, ...);
imagepng ($image);
```

This works fine, except that part of the copied image might be black, and/or the text might be black. This then also becomes transparent, which is something I **don't** want.

```
imagefill ($image, 0,0, 0x7FFF0000);
imagetransparent ($image, 0x7FFF0000);
```

The above code is something I found online, which fills it with red, then makes red transparent. Again, this causes all red in the image to become transparent. I could choose a color that is unlikely to occur, but I can't guarantee this.

Is there something I'm missing? Can this be fixed?
Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`imagecolortransparent` is probably not what you want here if you're merging images, as single-colour transparency is nasty.

Instead, try it with a transparent fill mask like so:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

// Transparent Background
imagealphablending($image, false);
$transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparency);
imagesavealpha($image, true);

// Drawing over
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($image, 25, 25, 75, 75, $black);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

Comment: imagealphablending defaults to true on true color images so this does nothing different :)
Also, imagecreatetruecolor creates a black image, which is why the first piece of code uses imagecolortransparent (0);

Comment: In that case, I fail to see your problem. I tested the above by drawing a black rectangle in the centre, and it's working just fine with transparency around.

Comment: Really? Then something is probably wrong with my setup, because if I try the following code, I get a blue rectangle with black surrounding it!

    $image = imagecreatetruecolor (800,600);
    imagealphablending ($image, true);
    imagefilledrectangle ($image, 50,50, 750, 550, imagecolorallocate ($image, 0,0,128));
    header ('Content-type: image/PNG');
imagepng ($image);

Comment: @user2139592 Actually, don't jump too quickly to that conclusion as the server I'm trying had a modified PHP/GD on there. I'm trying it out on a different server now.